# Can't query all records from my table in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have been working on a project which can register pupil records but it throws an error when I try querying the PupilRecord table in the database. The error thrown is AttributeError: type object 'PupilRecord' has no attribute 'query_all'

Here is my model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))

class PupilRecord(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "PupilRecord"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(20))
    lname = db.Column(db.String(20))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    admno = db.Column(db.String(15))
```

Here is the view I use to query

```
@app.route('/all_pupils')
@login_required
def all_pupils():
    myPupils = PupilRecord.query_all()
    return render_template('all_pupils.html', myPupils=myPupils)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: First create an instance of your class

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/queryclass

Comment: Thanks. Found the error. Was a typo. Had used query_all() instead of query.all()